# What are existing online forums where academics congregate that would welcome being informed about this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In order to promote the site, it would be good to post a notification on some of the existing online forums where academics congregate.

- What online forums exist?

As side points

- What community does the forum contain? How big is the community?
- What rules exist regarding promoting other site in the community?

By way of example:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/AcademicPsychology/ contains almost 2000 subscribers; Reddit permits posting links; links that the community likes get upvoted and then receive greater exposure.

Comment: I think reddit is a good point, and the subreddit http://www.reddit.com/r/compsci might also be interested.

Answer (score 4):

- [Physics Forums](http://www.physicsforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=139). Check the Academic Guidance forum. Even people in other fields (like chemistry) end up going there.
- Reddits like [AskAcademia](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia) and the private subreddit known as ScienceLounge (you have to be a panelist in [/r/AskScience](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience) to get in, but being a panelist isn't difficult at all).
- [The Grad Cafe](http://www.thegradcafe.com)
- [PhysicsGRE.com](http://www.physicsgre.com)
- [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Graduate-School) (the Academia and Graduate School sections)
- PhDComics used to have a Proceedings forum but now it's gone
- [The Graduate School subforum of College Confidential](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/graduate-school/)
- [The Chronicle](http://chronicle.com/forums/) (though the forums there are more for faculty members)

Comment: I've posted this morning a link in /r/AskAcademia

Comment: FWIW we hit a lot of roadblocks trying to "advertise" Physics Stack Exchange on Physics Forums. So if anyone makes any headway with them, I'd be very interested to hear how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be worthwhile to advertise on the Metas of existing academic or close-to-academic SEs. A partial list of ones I am familiar and see academics active on:

- [cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)
- [cogsci.SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)
- [linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

I think it is alright to mention SE sites on the metas, but this will only come to the attention of the 'regulars' who tend to be pretty abreast with new SE sites anyways, so it might not get that many new academics.

Answer (score 2):

[Academia.edu](http://academia.edu/) - social networking for people in Academia. I think they're claiming to have just passed 1 million users.

Comment: I wonder how we could promote cogsci.se to relevant users of academia.edu?